# Cannot destroy Azure Databricks group membership from system groups with Terraform

Tags: terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I am attempting to manage my Azure Databricks users and groups with Terraform, using the `databrickslabs/databricks` provider. Something like this:

```
resource "databricks_group" "group" {
  display_name = var.group_name
  force        = true

  allow_cluster_create       = false
  allow_instance_pool_create = false
  databricks_sql_access      = true
  workspace_access           = true
}

resource "databricks_user" "user" {
  user_name    = var.user_mail
  display_name = var.user_name
  force        = true
}

resource "databricks_group_member" "membership" {
  group_id  = databricks_group.group.id
  member_id = databricks_user.user.id
}
```

This is all deployed through my Azure service principal, as part of a larger codebase that also provisions the Databricks Workspace...and it works great.

However, if I add users to one of the Databricks built-in groups (`admins` or `users`), while the deployment works, `terraform destroy` -- again, running as my service principal -- gives the following error when trying to destroy the `databricks_group_member.membership` resource:

> Error: cannot delete group member: PERMISSION_DENIED: Requesting user '0a19c919-7b10-499d-acd4-057944582a41' does not have permission to edit system groups.

Why can my service principal define group membership, but not delete it? Is there some special Databricks permission I can give my service principal -- when I create the workspace -- which will resolve this? Otherwise, I have to manually do `terraform state rm` on the resource to get the `destroy` to go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`users` is a built-in group that contains all users of the workspace, you can't remove user from it, but you also shouldn't add users explicitly into it. You can remove user, then it will be removed from `users` as well.  If you're afraid about having too broad permissions for all users, you can revoke as much as possible from the `users` group, and set specific permissions for each group.

Regarding `admins` group, the [example from documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/user#example-usage) works just fine - you add user, put it into the `admins` group:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # databricks_group_member.i-am-admin will be created
  + resource "databricks_group_member" "i-am-admin" {
      + group_id  = "5662462700018557"
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + member_id = (known after apply)
    }

  # databricks_user.me will be created
  + resource "databricks_user" "me" {
      + active                     = true
      + allow_cluster_create       = false
      + allow_instance_pool_create = false
      + databricks_sql_access      = false
      + display_name               = (known after apply)
      + id                         = (known after apply)
      + user_name                  = "me@example.com"
      + workspace_access           = false
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
databricks_user.me: Creating...
databricks_user.me: Creation complete after 2s [id=3766754836829044]
databricks_group_member.i-am-admin: Creating...
databricks_group_member.i-am-admin: Creation complete after 1s [id=5662462700018557|3766754836829044]

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

and when you remove this user from `admins` group by removing the `databricks_group_member` resource, it just removed without error, but user will stay a member of `users` group:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # databricks_group_member.i-am-admin will be destroyed
  - resource "databricks_group_member" "i-am-admin" {
      - group_id  = "5662462700018557" -> null
      - id        = "5662462700018557|3766754836829044" -> null
      - member_id = "3766754836829044" -> null
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
databricks_group_member.i-am-admin: Destroying... [id=5662462700018557|3766754836829044]
databricks_group_member.i-am-admin: Destruction complete after 1s

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 1 destroyed.
```

Comment: Thank you :) That did the trick... Although I had to pass through the `admins` group ID from the caller module to avoid dependency resolution problems.